# Why is `id` ignored by an enum in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I ran into an issue with my app earlier today, when I was trying to conditionally render elements based on whether or not a value exists in an enum. Here is the simplified code:

```
enum Enum {
    'id',
    'name',
    'age'
}

['id', 'name', 'age'].forEach((val) => {
    console.log('in enum: ', !!Enum[val])
})
```

This prints,

```
"in enum: ",  false 
"in enum: ",  true 
"in enum: ",  true
```

I ended up doing something like,

```
. . .
if (!!Enum[val] && val === 'id') {
    // code
}
. . .
```

Am I missing something? Is `id` some sort of reserved value for enums?

Comment: `Enum.id` is `0`, and `!!0` is `false`.  Is this a typo or a ... brain-o?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `!!Enum[val]` you're testing enum value not enum key:

```
console.log(!!0) //prints false
console.log(!!1) //prints true
console.log(!!2) //prints true
```

Your code should look like this:

```
['id', 'name', 'age'].forEach((val: any) => {
    console.log('in enum: ', (val in Enum))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`id, name, age` it is NOT `values`. It's `KEYS` for `default valuses`. Example: `enum Enum { 'id = 0','name = 1', 'age = 2' }` - it is default valuses. You by KEY asks for a `VALUE`

For example:

```
    enum Enum {
        'id' = 'a',
        'name' = 'b',
        'age' = 'c'
    }
    
    ['id', 'name', 'age'].forEach((val: any) => {
        console.log('in enum: ', Enum[val])
    })
    // result -> a, b, c
```